# Populate C# Class from simple SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, oop, webforms, sql-server-2012

I am creating a page that will display the most recent record of an audit table in our database which I can get using the following query.

```
select top 1 StartDateTime, EndDateTime, Status 
from Audit
order by StartDateTime desc
```

As this info will be used multiple times throughout my application I wanted to create a class that would read in the row and populate a "stats" object that I could call from any page.

My class currently looks like

```
public class Stats
{
    public DateTime startDate() {

        string mySQL;
        mySQL = "select top 1 StartDateTime from Audit order by StartDateTime desc";

        string myConnectionString;
        myConnectionString = "databaseCS";

        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[myConnectionString].ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(mySQL, myConnection);

        using (myConnection)
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            DateTime startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(myCommand.ExecuteScalar());
            return startDate;
        }

    }
    public DateTime endDate() 
    {
        string mySQL;
        mySQL = "select top 1 EndDateTime from Audit order by StartDateTime desc";

        string myConnectionString;
        myConnectionString = "databaseCS";

        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[myConnectionString].ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(mySQL, myConnection);

        using (myConnection)
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            DateTime endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(myCommand.ExecuteScalar());
            return endDate;
        }
    }

    public string status() {

        string mySQL;
        mySQL = "select top 1 EndDateTime from Audit order by StartDateTime desc";

        string myConnectionString;
        myConnectionString = "databaseCS";

        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[myConnectionString].ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(mySQL, myConnection);

        using (myConnection)
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            string status = Convert.ToString(myCommand.ExecuteScalar());
            return status;
        }


    }
```

The pages that will be displaying the data will more often than not be displaying at least 2 of these statistics hence multiple database queries which I want to avoid.

Is there a way I can change my code to query the database once?

Many thanks

Comment: How are you querying the database? You need to show something or we are guessing.

Comment: apologies, just editing now

Comment: `"would require the database to be queried multiple times"` - Why?  You have a database query in your question which returns the data you want, don't you?  Execute that query once and you have the data you want.  What exactly is the problem here?  Are you just asking how to use a database in C#?

Comment: are you using  Entity Framework or ado.net (sqlClient)

Comment: @David thanks for your response, by "multiple times" I meant I thought I could add the code to query the database to each of the set methods. A lot of the time the web application will require all the stats hence multiple calls which will result in multiple DB queries. Are you saying I can put the database query outside of the set methods? (Apologies if im using the wrong terminology I'm an OOP noob)

Comment: @SimonTindall: It's not really clear what you're describing.  But if you're querying *the same data* from the database then you don't need to re-fetch that same data again.  You can store information locally in an application in a variety of different ways.  Maybe you can elaborate in the question with an example of what you're doing and why you're re-querying the database?

Comment: @David ok, i'll edit the question. Apologies.

Comment: @David I've edited the question now, i hope that is more clear

Comment: @SimonTindall: In the original SQL query you're selecting all three fields.  Why in your code do you only select one at a time?  Just select all three, like you already intended to do.  For example maybe select them in the constructor for that class and store the values in class-level variables, which can then be returned by those methods.

Answer (score -1):

A more robust example

```
  public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        //Internal reference to the cache wrapper object
        private static ICacheService _internalCacheObject;

        //Public mehtod used to inject a new caching service into the application.
        // This method is required to ensure full testability. 
        public void RegisterCacheService(ICacheService cacheService)
        {
            _internalCacheObject = cacheService;
        }

        //Use this property to access the underlying cache object from within
        // controller methods. Use this instead of native Cache object.
        public static ICacheService CacheService
        {
            get { return _internalCacheObject; }
        }
        protected void Application_Start()
        { 
            //Inject a global caching service
            RegisterCacheService(new AspNetCacheService());
            //Store some sample app-wide data
            CacheService["StartTime"] = DateTime.Now; 
            //Call the cache service 
            // var data = MyNameSpace.MvcApplication.CacheService[...];
        }

    }
```

Interface

```
public interface ICacheService
    {
        Object Get(String key);
        void Set(String key, Object data);
        Object this[String key] { get; set; }
    }
```

Class

```
public class AspNetCacheService : ICacheService
    {
        private readonly Cache _aspnetCache;
        public AspNetCacheService()
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            {
                _aspnetCache = HttpContext.Current.Cache;
            }
        }
        public Object Get(String key)
        {
            return _aspnetCache[key];
        }
        public void Set(String key, Object data)
        {
            _aspnetCache[key] = data;
        }
        public object this[String name]
        {
            get { return _aspnetCache[name]; }
            set { _aspnetCache[name] = value; }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -2):

In the Application_start() of the Global.asax make a call for the datatable or dataset from the query, then save it to session

```
      protected void Application_Start()
      {
        string query = "your query";
         ///Typically you would have some sort of datalayer
        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(conSTR);
        sqlConn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConn);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        sqlConn.Close();

        ///Create Stat object
        Stats stat = new Stats();
        stat.startDate = dt.Columns["startDate"];
       //etc
       Session["stats"] = stat;
}
```

Then on the page

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     Stats stat = Session["stats"] as Stats;
      }
```